# Change mime type pictures before save it on server

Tags: php, image, converters, mime

I have code:

```
//Get image from form
$image = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
//Convert to base64
$imageData = base64_encode(file_get_contents($image));
//Set mime type
header('Content-Type: image/gif');
//Decode to image
$image = base64_decode($imageData);
//Save in server
$res = file_put_contents(ROOT_DIR . "/uploads/fotos/" . $row['user_id'] . ".gif", $image);
```

The problem is that it is at this point header ('Content-Type: image / gif'); displays the image in the browser. How do I change the mime type does not output the result to the browser. The ultimate goal of saving all the images on a server in the format and type of gif.

Comment: You only have to do MIME types when you're feeding the image to the browser. If you're just saving it as a file on the server, what you're doing should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just uploading the image onto the server then you need not to use

```
header('Content-Type: image/gif');// remove this
```

it is used to output the image file to the browser.
if everything is ok then to upload file use php file upload function

```
move_uploaded_file ( string $filename , string $destination )
```